# React server side rendering wrong page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pug

In my `app.js` I have two parts...

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/register', reg);
```

An index part and a register part.

In my `index.js` I am rendering the following...

```
var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var RegApp = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));

router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(RegApp({exists: false}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
```

This is calling the following react component to be rendered...

```
class RegApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){

        return (    
            <Register />
        );
    }
}
module.exports = RegApp;
```

So the first page a user will see is the `<Register />` component. Now, in my other route, the `register.js` I am querying the db and rendering the page based on the result.

In short I am attempting to render another component to replace the one I rendered above...

```
var React = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom/server');
var App = React.createFactory(require('../components/index'));

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
//Here I query the db

...
    console.log("query success");
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(App({exists: true}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
```

The component that this is trying to render is the following...

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render(){

        return (    
            <Index />
        );
    }
}
module.exports = App;
```

The problem is, this component never gets rendered. The page refreshes and renders the first component `<Register />` instead of `<Index />`. This is all very confusing because the console prints `query success`, but still the page is not rendered. Even if I put a `console.log` inside of the `App` component's render method, it gets printed out but the page is not rendered. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing in the Register component for the path: /

```
router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var reactHtml = reactDom.renderToString(RegApp({exists: false}));
    res.render('../../tutorHub/views/index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
```

Either the path should be /register in the above or the component should be the App component.

Comment: I still get the same problem